# Ranking System (ELO)

Tags: statistics, algorithms

I want to create a ranking system for a sports game, where more that 2 "teams/players" participate in each match. This means NOT chess, or soccer, or boxing. It could be bowling or long jump etc. For example let's say it's running 100m.

One way of doing so is that every player gets 3 points for 1st place, 2 points for 2nd place and 1 point for 3rd place. But I don't want the ranking to be accumulative. I want to gain and lose points, so that your score represent your current form.

So I thought of the ELO rating system. Assuming that every player has an ELO before the match, these are some variations i have thought so far:

1) calculate an expected time for each player. then, according to his time he either gains or loses ELO points

2) assume that every player is having a mini-match with every other player. Then we just look if a player has won or lost a mini-match, regardless of his time.

Then I though of some modifications to second case:

2a) mini-match not with every other player, but only with N number of players each time. These players will be the players whose ELO is closer to yours.

2b) discard matches where less than M players participate.

- Do you find any flaws to my thoughts?
- Do you have something else to propose?

**Edit**: Any abstract ideas are fine to be proposed. I need as many different ideas possible. I will be able to figure out then which to implement.

Comment: I don't see how you can reasonably choose an ordering on which match gets applied first.

Comment: @JessicaK If I understand your worry: you just calculate all N minimatches with the ELO you had before the match, and then update your ELO

Comment: I feel like this could have an odd effect on rating inflation. Suppose you are running a 64k "Speed-Walking World Championship" with 200 participants. If you consider just the first place winner and suppose his ELO is roughly the mean of the 200 participants ELO ratings, this single tournament win is going to make his ELO astronomical and not a good basis for comparing skill level.

Comment: i am just comparing with N players. let's say N=5. so i will compare with 5 out of 200. these are the 5 competitors who have similar ELO to me before the run. You can also assume that after every match I divide the elo_won or elo_lost with the number of mini-matches (5 for our case).

Comment: Online gaming may have tackled this problem already for you. Microsoft use a system called TrueSkill for xBox Live, which you can read about at http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67956/NIPS2006_0688.pdf. DotA2, et al use a different system called Match Making Ranking, or MMR. The details of this were hard for me to find by googling, but emailing someone at Valve occasionally produces good results.

Comment: By the way, why is ELO all in caps? It is named after Dr Arpad Elo, who was (is?)  a a human, not an acronym.

Comment: @IgorRivin From wikipedia: It is in caps so as to distinguish it from the name of Dr Arpad.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

1. Take a discounted average of past finish times. That is, suppose there is a race each month $m$, and some associated finish time $t_{im}$ for runner $i$, then the discounted average is $$DA_i=\frac{\sum_{m=0} \delta^m t_{im}}{\sum_{m=0} \delta^m},$$
   where $m=0$ is the current month and then we count backwards. $0<\delta<1$ is the discount factor. In effect, a time $t$ gets less weight the farther in the past it is - this reflects current shape. (This can also be viewed as the predicted running time for a new race.)
2. Use a multinomial logit model. Logit models are very popular in empirical applications. They help you predict the probabilities that some runner wins a match given some characteristics, like number of contenders.
3. Use forecasts from betting or prediction markets. If you try to classify actual 100m runners, then the public has an often very accurate forecast of who is going to win, which you can find out by looking at betting odds or prediction market prices. In these markets, people stake money on their beliefs, so only people who are reasonably sure that they are right actually bet, which makes these forecasts pretty accurate (there is a lot of empirical research on this). Of course, this doesn't work for runners which are not featured on tv.